# Python NameError: name is not defined for my script

Tags: python, nameerror

I have a python script and I am receiving the following error. I'm a new learner to this language, so I created a simple script, called writing.py, to write participant names and scores into a text file named scores.txt. But I keep getting this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "writing.py", line 4, in <module>
    participant = input("Participant name > ")
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
NameError: name 'Helen' is not defined
```

Here is my code:

```
f = open("scores.txt", "w")

    while True:
        participant = input("Participant name > ")

        if participant == "quit":
            print("Quitting...")
            break

    score = input("Score for " + participant + "> ")
    f.write(participant + "," + score + "\n")

f.close()
```

Comment: The name Helen is just the user input. It applies to any participant name I add.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I am guessing you are using `Python 2.x` , in Python 2.x , [`input`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#input) actually tries to evaluate the input before returning the result, hence if you put in some name , it will treat that as a variable and try to get its value causing the issue.

Use [`raw_input()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#raw_input). instead. Example -

```
participant = raw_input("Participant name > ")
....
score = raw_input("Score for " + participant + "> ")
```

Answer (score 1):

You're using Python 2. In Python 2, [`input`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#input) takes your input and tries to evaluate it. You want to use [`raw_input`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#raw_input).